# Scrapy - offsite request to be processed based on a regex

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have to crawl 5-6 domains. I wanted to write a the crawler as such that the offsite requests if contains a some substrings example set as  [ aaa,bbb,ccc]
if the offsite url contain a substring from the above set then it should be processed and not filter out. Should i write a custom middleware or can i just use regular expression in the allowed domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offsite middleware already uses regex by default, however it's no exposed. It compiles the domains you provide into regex, but the domains are escaped so providing regex code in `allowed_domains` would not work.

What you can do though is extend that middleware and override `get_host_regex()` method to implement your own offsite policy.

The original code in `scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware`:

```
def get_host_regex(self, spider):
    """Override this method to implement a different offsite policy"""
    allowed_domains = getattr(spider, 'allowed_domains', None)
    if not allowed_domains:
        return re.compile('') # allow all by default
    regex = r'^(.*\.)?(%s)$' % '|'.join(re.escape(d) for d in allowed_domains if d is not None)
    return re.compile(regex)
```

You can just override to return your own regex:

```
# middlewares.py    
class MyOffsiteMiddleware(OffsiteMiddleware):
    def get_host_regex(self, spider):
        allowed_regex = getattr(spider, 'allowed_regex', '') 
        return re.compile(allowed_regex)

# spiders/myspider.py 
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    allowed_regex = '.+?\.com'

# settings.py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.MyOffsiteMiddleware': 666,
}
```

Comment: will this allow me to crawl certain url which contains substring as specified by me ?

Comment: cause i got to this when i asked question.

Comment: @RishiSaraswat Yes. With the example I provided you can set `allowed_regex = 'aaa|bbb|ccc'`

Comment: @RishiSaraswat great, could you accept the question so other people could find it easier :)