# Scrapy fails to crawl recursively when two rules are set

Tags: python, scrapy

[image: I've tried to upload what I can see in the console]I've written a script in scrapy to crawl a website recursively. But for some reason it's not being able to. I've tested xpaths in sublime and it is working perfectly. So, at this point I can't fix what I've done wrong.

"items.py" includes:

```
import scrapy
class CraigpItem(scrapy.Item):
    Name = scrapy.Field()
    Grading = scrapy.Field()
    Address = scrapy.Field()
    Phone = scrapy.Field()
    Website = scrapy.Field()
```

The spider named "craigsp.py" includes:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule 
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class CraigspSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigsp"
    allowed_domains = ["craigperler.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.americangemsociety.org/en/find-a-jeweler']
    rules=[Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//area')),
               Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="jeweler__link"]'),callback='parse_items')]    

    def parse_items(self, response):
        page = response.xpath('//div[@class="page__content"]')
        for titles in page:
            AA= titles.xpath('.//h1[@class="page__heading"]/text()').extract()
            BB= titles.xpath('.//p[@class="appraiser__grading"]/strong/text()').extract()
            CC = titles.xpath('.//p[@class="appraiser__hours"]/text()').extract()
            DD = titles.xpath('.//p[@class="appraiser__phone"]/text()').extract()
            EE = titles.xpath('.//p[@class="appraiser__website"]/a[@class="appraiser__link"]/@href').extract()
            yield {'Name':AA,'Grading':BB,'Address':CC,'Phone':DD,'Website':EE}
```

The command I'm running with is:

```
scrapy crawl craigsp -o items.csv
```

Hope somebody will lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Filtered offsite request

This error means that a url that was queued to scrapy does not pass `allowed_domains` setting.

You have:

```
allowed_domains = ["craigperler.com"]
```

And your spider is trying to crawl http://ww.americangemsociety.org. You either need to add it to the `allowed_domains` list or get rid of this setting  entirely.

Comment: @SMth80 unforutantely this setting does not support wildcards and so by default so you need to enter all domains you are expecting by hand. However you can extend this functionality quite easily by extending one middleware, which would allow regex patterns to be used (e.g. `.+\.com` to allow all .com domains). See my answer on this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093211/scrapy-offsite-request-to-be-processed-based-on-a-regex/39098601#39098601